# How to re-open a hidden form with the same data Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

After clicking a label, the current form is set to hide while another form is opened. It will either open the form if its never been opened, or redisplay the form with all the previous data on it when it has previously been opened. When reopening, it would be more efficient for it to keep the same data, but it can just run the load procedure again as it's reading from a database.

Every time I run this code, it reopens the form but doesn't have all of the previous data which gets filled by the load procedure. It also removes the label that links to the form you just came from.

```
Private Sub lblHistory_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblHistory.Click
    Try
        frmStudentHistory.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
        frmStudentHistory.ShowInTaskbar = True
        frmStudentHistory.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End Try
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is frmStudentHistory the name of your form class? It looks like you're using the default instance of a Form. You can look through Application.OpenForms to see if your form is there and show it from there if needs be.

Comment: How are you closing `frmStudentHistory`? If you're doing a full exit of the form there's nothing for the form to save. You could use the `.visible.` property to just hide/show it instead; that would keep the data on it if it's already been opened once and you just hid it by setting it's visible property to false.

Comment: When I use the .visible property and set it to false to close it and then true to reopen it, I just get an 'exited with error code -1' message and the entire program stops

Comment: frmStudentHistory is also the name of my form class. When using Application.OpenForms, if it's found, how would you go about redisplaying the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew Mortimer pointed out, you can use Application.OpenForms to find any forms that are currently open in the application. This will return the reference to the open form which will have all the existing data still in place. I'm guessing you would like to open the original form when frmStudentHistory closes. To do this add an event handler to the *closing* event of the frmStudentHistory. Inside that handler add the code to find the existing form and open it.

```
// This is inside your frmStudentHistory and is the event handler for form closing event
private void frmStudentHistory_OnClosing(object sender, eventargs e){
    var returnForm = Application.OpenForms.Item(FormToOpen.Name);
    if(returnForm != null){
        returnForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
}
```

Note: this only works with Minimized windows. If setting the window to Hide or ShowInTaskbar = False the Form will not be found in OpenForms.

I would suggest looking into using [MDI Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) (Multiple-Document Interface). It is meant for applications with multiple forms.

To do this designate a Form to be the container (IsMdiContainer = true in Properties window). Then create a public method that all other forms will use to open forms.

C#

```
public class MdiContainer {
    // this goes inside the Form designated as the MdiContainer
    public void OpenForm(Form formToOpen){
        Form frm = null;
        foreach(Form child in this.MDIChildren){
           // check if the form already exists as a child in the MDI container
            if(child.Name == formToOpen.Name)
                frm = child;
        }

        // if the form doesn't exist get a new instance
        if frm == null
            frm = FormFactory.GetForm(FormToOpen.Name);

       // set form properties and show
        frm.MdiParent = this;
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        frm.BringToFront();
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

VB.Net

```
Public Class MdiContainer
    Public Sub OpenForm(ByVal formToOpen As Form)
        Dim frm As Form = Nothing

        For Each child As Form In Me.MDIChildren
            If child.Name = formToOpen.Name Then frm = child
        Next

        If frm Is Nothing Then frm = FormFactory.GetForm(FormToOpen.Name)
        frm.MdiParent = Me
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        frm.BringToFront()
        frm.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I like to use a factory class to get a new form instance when needed.

C#

```
public class FormFactory{
    public static Form GetForm(string formName){
        switch(formName.ToLower()){
            case Form1.Name.ToLower():
                return new Form1;
            case Form2.Name.ToLower():
                return new Form2;
            default:
                return new ErrorForm;
        }
    }
}
```

VB.Net

```
Public Class FormFactory
    Public Shared Function GetForm(ByVal formName As String) As Form
        Select Case formName.ToLower()
            Case Form1.Name.ToLower()
                Return New Form1()
            Case Form2.Name.ToLower()
                Return New Form2()
            Case Else
                Return New ErrorForm()
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

With this setup we can retrieve Forms that have already been created or create a new form if one does not exist.

C#

```
public class Form1{
    private void lblHistory_Click(..){
        MdiContainer.OpenForm(Form2);
    }
} 

public class Form2{
    private void Form2_Closing(...){
        MdiContainer.OpenForm(Form1);
    } 
}
```

VB.Net

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub lblHistory_Click()
        MdiContainer.OpenForm(Form2)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Closing()
        MdiContainer.OpenForm(Form1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The question was for vb.net. This is C#.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It led me along the right track and without it, I'd still be stuck at square 1. In the end, I ended up making some code that solved the problem but your answer definitely gave me a massive boost. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Mary You're right, sorry about that. I've added the VB.Net equivalent code.